# Changing the title tag from a shortcode

Tags: shortcode, seo, title, headers

I currently have a shortcode which dynamically swaps out locations on a page to make each page specific to a location.

For example the url

```
http://mywebsite.com/offers/scotland/
```

Would make the H1 of my website be

```
Special Offers Scotland
```

But now I also want to change the title tag to allow effect search engine optimisation. I am unsure if it's possible to do this within my shortcode as it will execute within the loop and therefore the header.php has already finished loading.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't do this. Better build a custom meta box that allows the author to change the post's page title

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the way it has to be done! There will only ever be 1 variable throughout the associated pages and that is the location.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your thinking that because the loop evaluates after the header you will not be able to get the contents of the loop there.

The easiest way to do this is probably with jQuery. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        document.title = 'blah';
    });
</script>
```

Place this code in your loop, and the page title will be changed on after the document is ready. This may not be a desirable solution however, because some search engines do not evaluate JavaScript. You can use [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) to see what the page looks like to the Google Crawler.

As an alternate solution, I believe [All in One SEO Pack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/all-in-one-seo-pack/) has the functionality that you describe:

- ***You can override any title and set any META description and any META keywords you want.***
- Support for Custom Post Types
- Advanced Canonical URLs
- Fine tune Page Navigational Links
- Built-in API so other plugins/themes can access and extend functionality
- Support for CMS-style WordPress installations
- Automatically optimizes your titles for search engines
- Generates META tags automatically
- Avoids the typical duplicate content found on WordPress blogs
- For beginners, you don't even have to look at the options, it works out-of-the-box. Just install.
- For advanced users, you can fine-tune everything

Comment: I have ruled out javascript as this site needs to be 100% crawler friendly as it is a marketing project. In regards to AIOSEOP, I don't have physical wordpress pages so I can't change these titles.

Comment: There is no meaning of changing title using JavaScript.